# Cambiar efecto de una fuente

Tags: html, html5, css

Tengo un wordpress con un tema en el que quiero personalizar un titulo que quiero que quede [así](http://typecast.com/preview/google/Herr%20Von%20Muellerhoff):

### [image: Título]

Pero la fuente queda [así](http://canvador.com/new/ejemplofuente):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Le he asignado manualmente [la fuente](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Herr+Von+Muellerhoff) que usa y otros efectos css:

```
.text--superior {
    margin-bottom: 15px !important;
    font-size: 59px;
    font-family: "Herr Von Muellerhoff" !important;
}
```

He intentado también `text-transform` pero tampoco da resultado

Como consigo quitar el exceso de cursiva que tiene actualmente la fuente?

[Puedes encontrar aquí una página para probar](http://canvador.com/new/ejemplofuente)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El estilo de la fuente está determinado por la propiedad `font-style`, esto es lo que determina que esté en `itálica`. El estado inicial es `normal` por lo que todo el texto debería mostrarse sin cursiva a menos que

- Un elemento hijo lo esté modificando
- Un estilo con más especificidad este siendo aplicado
- Esté puesto en `inherit` y esté heredando el valor de un elemento padre

En tu caso hay un elemento hijo modificándolo

[image: elemento modificando estilo]

Sólo tienes que eliminar el elemento `<em>` o crear una clase y aplicarsela

```
em.estilo-normal {
   font-style: normal;
}

<em class="estilo-normal">Esencia Rústica</em>
```

o podrías decirle que herede de su padre que ya lo trae en `normal`

```
em.estilo-normal {
    font-style: inherit;
}

<em class="estilo-normal">Esencia Rústica</em>
```

Por favor [no uses `!important`](https://github.com/CSSLint/csslint/wiki/Disallow-!important) si no es estrictamente necesario. Siempre es considerado una mala práctica y no es nada que no se pueda solucionar con clases que tengan mayor [especificidad](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Comment: madre mia que ceguera!!!! gracias!!!!